# Sessions being destroyed under high traffic

Tags: php, session

I'm working in a production environment where users are being logged out frequently. Some times are worse than others, but the trigger almost always seems to be when a user tries to open multiple pages simultaneously.

The sessions stores various information, including a login string and user id, which are used for authentication. If authentication fails, the user is redirected to a login page.

I have implemented a few checks to see what is going on;

I check to ensure the session has been started with `session_status`. This comes back as having an active session.

I also attempt to output the session variables, but they return as not being set.

I also compare the session ID, and is different from the previous one.

I do not have full access to all PHP configurations, but I do know the session is set to expire after 5 hours, but the sessions are getting destroyed much more often, sometimes within minutes.

What are some possible causes, or additional troubleshooting steps I can take to resolve this issue?

We are using a custom session function, and it does regenerate the session everytime (disabling this does not resolve the issue). The function is:

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

Comment: different session ID = new sessions being created. the old ones are there, but abandoned/orphaned. that means you get a fresh/clean/empty $_SESSION. you need to check the cookie settings and make sure that they're consistent across all session-using pages.

Comment: @MarcB That is true, coming to think of it, we do regenerate the session on every page. Disabling this did not resolve the issue though. I'll update my question with our session function.

Comment: ah. if you're regenerating, than that'd explain the changing IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Check your session expiry. By default php on-disk sessions are not cleaned up at every start of a php script (see http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) so on low volume sites it's very possible for sessions that *should* have expired to be treated as valid, while on busy sites this is less likely as there are more chances for the session garbage collector to run.

Comment: How would this be applicable to my problem?

Comment: Your question specifically says it happens under high traffic. If your php environment is setup to run session GC 1:100 (1%) at times of low traffic sessions won't be cleaned as quickly after they've expired as they will at times of high traffic.

Comment: By high traffic, I mean one of 10 people opening 4-5 pages simultaneously. But if it is an active session, why would it be removed by garbage collection?

Comment: Each request had a chance to trigger GC. More requests, more chance it is triggered sooner.

Comment: Your answer is still confusing, it's worded as though my problem is sessions that should be deleted are not, which is the opposite of my problem.

Comment: Your question says under higher traffic, sessions are deleted when you believe they shouldn't be. One possible cause is php's session TTL being shorter than you want, and a low gc probability "hides" this issue during times of low traffic

Comment: `gc_probability` is set to 0.